# Как соединить две картинки в одну?

Tags: java, android, bitmap

В папке *drawable* находятся 2 картинки image1.png и image2.png. Для того, чтобы вывести любую из них на экран я создаю bitmap таким способом.

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), resID);
```

И вывожу с помощью drawBitmap. Но появилась необходимость объединить эти две картинки в одну (для удобства использования). Причём я не могу это сделать заранее в Фотошопе. Мне нужна возможность в процессе выполнения программы объединить две картинки в одну. Например, я беру первую картинку и к её правому верхнему пикселю приклеиваю вторую картинку левым верхним пикселем. И в результате получаю новый Bitmap большего размера содержащего обе картинки сразу. И выводить его на экран я могу одной командой. Подскажите, как это можно сделать?

Comment: Сделайте два imageview друг за другом. Правый скройте при необходимости

Comment: @ Arty Morris, вы считаете, что получить единую картинку Невозможно?

Comment: Можно, но нафига усложнять?

Comment: @ Arty Morris, мне нужно будет общую картинку вращать вокруг одного центра, масштабировать относительно другого центра, возможно ещё какие-то преобразования. Сделать это над разными картинками, как будто это одна картинка намного более сложно, чем слить их в одну.

Comment: @gibsonff, так поместите эти две картинки на панельку-лейаут-кнопку-[любой другой элемент] и преобразовывайте-вращайте на здоровье! Я тоже согласен, что проще позиционировать 2 картинки (и вывести их с помощью чего-нибудь вроде Picasso), чем городить огород с битмапами